# Visual basic ComboBox.SelectedIndex

Tags: vb.net, combobox, selecteditem, selectedindex

I develop a vb.net application, and I'm having troubles with comboboxes.

I have this to know when the selected item on my combobox is changed :

```
Private Sub ComboBoxSite_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex <> 0) Then 'If it is not the default value
        Console.WriteLine("ActionListenerIndex = {0}", ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex) 'To debug
        RequestAccesv2(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

And the RequestAccessv2() function

```
Private Sub RequestAccesv2(taille As Integer)
    initBoxesLocation() 'A function that clear/refill 4 comboBoxes
    Console.WriteLine("SELECTED INDEX SITE : {0}", ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex)
        Select Case taille
            Case 0 ..... 'Some database treatment

End Sub
```

And there is the result on the output, when the second function is called, I don't have the same selectedIndex :

```
ActionListenerIndex = 2
SELECTED INDEX SITE : -1 'Does it means thas nothing is selected ?
```

Have you already had/solved this problem ?

Regards,
Fabien

Comment: What is the code of _initBoxesLocation_ ? It appears that you change in some way the SelectedIndex in that function. Please [edit] your question adding that code

Comment: If you "clear/refill comboboxes" then the selected item will be removed, and the `SelectedIndex` reset back to `-1`

Comment: Actually the first item is at index 0. So `If (ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex <> 0) Then` won't pass when you change from second index to first. Was this intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers !

Indeed Steve and A Friend the problem was coming from the function initBoxesLocation.
In this fuction I was clearing 4 comboboxes, then I added 1 item on each.

I didn't realy understand where does the problem comes.

edit : Yes of course, once my comboboxes refiled I didn't selected an item again so there is the problem.

```
Private Sub initBoxesLocation()
    Console.WriteLine("initialisation entete")
    initBoxEnteteSite()
    initBoxEnteteBuilding()
    initBoxEnteteModule()
    initBoxEnteteRoom()
End Sub
```

I split the initBoxesLocation() function, by calling one or an other reset function depending on the combobox changed, I needed actually not to call them all.

Now it works !

Regards Fabien

Answer (score 0):

Data indices are non-negative. Index -1 represents no selection. If looking for when a valid index is selected, check for 0 or greater.

```
Private Sub ComboBoxSite_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex >= 0) Then 'If it is not the default value
        Console.WriteLine("ActionListenerIndex = {0}", ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex) 'To debug
        RequestAccesv2(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx

**ComboBox.SelectedIndex Property**

**Property Value**

Type: System.Int32
A zero-based index of the currently selected item.

A value of negative one (-1) is returned if no item is selected.

Now, you may want to ignore the first value, then use `ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex >= 1`. However, if the user selects the second, then the first, do you still want to ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

When no item is selected, -1 will be returned.  This is what is typically checked for:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxSite_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex <> -1) Then ' If something is selected
        Console.WriteLine("ActionListenerIndex = {0}", ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex) 'To debug
        RequestAccesv2(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

If you have a value in the first slot that shouldn't be selected, then you can check to make sure it is >= 1 instead:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxSite_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex >= 1) Then ' If it is not the default value at index 0 (zero), and something is selected
        Console.WriteLine("ActionListenerIndex = {0}", ComboBoxSite.SelectedIndex) 'To debug
        RequestAccesv2(0)
    End If
End Sub
```